# How to resume Django test suite from the last error/failure?

Tags: django, testing

I have a large test suite (1000+ tests), running for a total of 3-4 minutes, or until the first error pops up (running with `--failfast`). When a test fails and I fix it, I'd like to start from that test and continue running the other tests. (I know that a change may affect the previous tests, but running them every time seems wasteful)

Looking at `python manage.py test --help`, I see no option to run the test suite starting from the last failure. How can it be done?

Comment: Typically one does not stop at the first error, since you want a list of everything that can go wrong. You can use `--failed` to only rerun the failed tests.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're right, I should have mentioned I run it with `--failfast`.

Comment: You can run tests by app so it doesn't take as long. If your suite makes it through apps 1-2 and fails in 3, restart your test and don't include apps 1/2?

Comment: You can also run the tests in `--parallel`, which runs a test on every core.

Comment: @augustomen did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry @Walucas, there is none.

Comment: I asked almost an identical question and figured out a somewhat hacky solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76879335/2057516