# Is there a way in Django to specify a starting/first test?

Tags: django, testing

My tests take a long time to run, and many times fixing one test often fixes multiple tests, so I often use `--failfast` to fix tests one by one in the order in which they error out.  I fix a test, then rerun to find the next failure that wasn't due to the same root cause as the one I just fixed.

The problem is that the tests take a long time to run and I have to wait through all the tests that I already know will pass.  *I'm aware that code changes to fix one test could break a previously run/successful test, but I'd prefer to handle that in a second run.*

What I would like to do is specify a "starting test" so that I only run the tests from the previous failure forward.  I don't see a way to do that using `python manage.py test`.  Is there a trick to get it to not test previously run tests and just pick up where it left off?

Comment: The docs have lots of info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: They do indeed, but they do not answer this question. They tell you roughly that the tests are ordered, but don't tell you precisely how. And it tells you you can shuffle them or reverse the order, but they don't say how to resume tests from a starting point. In order for me to do it, I'd have to look through the test in the console and specifically run the ones that are absent.

Comment: In fact, I wrote a script that `tee`s the output to a log file and can parse previously generated logs to only rerun failed tests, but that's different from this case. I suppose I could write another script that saves the test order from that log and can rerun from the first failure, or by test name, but that's a lot of work. I'm hoping that someone has a simpler solution.

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086510/how-to-resume-django-test-suite-from-the-last-error-failure although people responded more positively to it, with more thoughtful comments, despite it having less detail than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a way to do it, but it involves a package install, a 1 line code change in `settings.py` in your django project, and a slightly more complex test run:

1. Install [django-list-tests](https://pypi.org/project/django-list-tests/)
2. Edit your `settings.py` to add an item to the `INSTALLED_APP` list: `"django_list_tests",`
3. Run your tests in a specific order, with:

   ```
   python manage.py test --failfast `python manage.py list_tests`
   ```
4. To run from a specific test, forward, you can use a grep in the sub-command:

   ```
   python manage.py test --failfast `python manage.py list_tests | grep -A 9999 TEST_NAME_HERE`
   ```

It's a hacky imperfect solution and the package to install is old, but it works.

Comment: Wow.  This is working great! I just did a big refactor, and some mistake I made massively slowed down my tests more than usual from 25 minutes to 4-6 hours.  Using this method, I can skip tests I've fixed (which have not yet fixed the speed issue) and pick up where I left off! This is sweet! I made a bash function that takes an additional `--start` option with the test name that I want to start from. I don't know why this isn't a default feature...